# Handle html string in JSON in PowerShell

Tags: html, json, string, powershell, devops

I have a JSON file that contains an HTML string and been manipulating it using PowerShell however every time I convert it back to JSON it is making the HTML string not the same anymore.

Really need some help with this. Thanks!
Here is my JSON:

```
{
"count": 1,
"value": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fields": {
            
                       "System.Description": "<div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\"><div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-family:Arial, sans-serif;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);display:inline !important;\">Decision has been made to use HLS video format</span><br></span></div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-family:Arial, sans-serif;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);display:inline !important;\"><br></span></span></div><p style=\"margin:0cm 0cm 8pt;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-autospace:none;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\">We\ncan’t use YouTube or Vimeo to serve the videos because analytics required.</span></p></div>We\nneed to use an HTML5 Player in the Desktop web app</span></div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\"><br></span></div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><br></div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><br></div></div><br>",

        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the issues are the encoded characters when going from a custom object back to json. Here is a workaround:

```
$json = @'
{
"count": 1,
"value": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fields": {
            
                       "System.Description": "<div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\"><div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-family:Arial, sans-serif;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);display:inline !important;\">Decision has been made to use HLS video format</span><br></span></div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-family:Arial, sans-serif;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);display:inline !important;\"><br></span></span></div><p style=\"margin:0cm 0cm 8pt;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-autospace:none;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\">We\ncan’t use YouTube or Vimeo to serve the videos because analytics required.</span></p></div>We\nneed to use an HTML5 Player in the Desktop web app</span></div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;\"><br></span></div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><br></div><div style=\"margin:0px 0cm 0.000133333px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;\"><br></div></div><br>"

        }
    }
]}
'@
$obj = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
# Manipulate $obj in here
[regex]::Replace(($obj | ConvertTo-Json -depth 10),'\\u[0-9a-f]{4}',{param ($m) [regex]::Unescape($m)})
```

You can use the Regex class method `Unescape()` to convert unicode character codes.

Comment: I tried using this method and I am getting this weird character ">We\ncanâ€™t use"

Comment: @art-a-game It's the curly 'smart-quote' `’` in there. You need to save in UTF8 to keep that character of replace it into a normal apostrophe `'` Try `$obj = [regex]::Unescape(($obj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10)) -replace "’", "'"  # or even replace with '&apos;' or '&#39;'`

Comment: I have tried this out but the JSON is not created properly

Comment: @art-a-game Please explain inyour [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63175391/edit) what you have tried and what you mean by  _is not created properly_ Show examples